# Better Voice for Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am looking for a better alternative to the 'Alice' voice provided by Twilio. I am pretty sure Twilio only provides two basic default voices along with 'Alice', a more robust version able to more effectively enunciate text. The only problem is that 'Alice' does not sound as natural as other voices used by other services known to be using Twilio. Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to access a better voice? The messages in the call flows will be somewhat dynamic so I don't think using recordings would be practical.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Alice is our most advanced voice that supports additional languages and locales.

Some things you can try to make Alice work better for you might include looking at the [`<Pause>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/pause) for more deliberate separation between sentences.

If you'd like to get additional control as it sounds like you have experienced with other services using Twilio, you could consider prerecording the static parts and deliver them using [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) and only using [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) for your dynamic content, though I know this isn't ideal.

There are some additional hints here https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say#hints.

I hope this helps!